# Objective-C: Result of casting id to BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

Does the following function return `YES` if `object != nil`?

```
- (BOOL)boolForObject:(id)object {
    return (BOOL)object;
}
```

I've tested with `object = [[NSObject alloc] init]` but got mixed results.

Comment: I would imagine it would return YES in the case described in your question.

Comment: @progrmr explains why you'd be getting mixed results, but why are you attempting to cast anyway? Checking for `object != nil` works and is the convention for determining whether an object exists. You're spending more time on the method call than you're saving by doing a cast instead of pointer comparison (which is likely just a bitwise AND followed by a cmp0 anyway).

Comment: Or, if you prefer, you can use `!!object` rather than `object != nil`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A pointer is larger than a BOOL, so when you cast it will truncate and take only the 8 least significant bits of the pointer and make it a BOOL.  If those bits all happen to be zero then that is equivalent to NO.

So to answer your question, no it does not (well sometimes it will depending on the pointer value)

Here's an example with using Xcode 5.1.1 on 32 bit architecture:

```
void* p = (void*)0xfeeeff00;
BOOL  b = (BOOL)p;

NSLog(@"p=%08x (%lu), b=%08x (%lu)", (uint32_t)p, sizeof p, (uint32_t)b, sizeof b);
```

It prints out:

```
p=feeeff00 (4), b=00000000 (1)
```

Comment: For completeness: casting to `bool` or `_Bool` would work as expected, producing `true` for any non-nil pointer.

Comment: Also Mike Ash has a good explanation http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-12-14-objective-c-pitfalls.html

Comment: This solves a problem I have been trying to diagnose. Most excellent.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 7):

What is the actual purpose of your method?

If it's just to check whether an object is nil or not, why not do it like this:

```
- (BOOL)boolForObject:(id)object 
{
    return (object != nil);
}
```

It's more obvious what the result will be.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do:

```
return !!object;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, but

```
return object != nil;
```

will.